# Android Studio: Physical Device disconnects automatically from Device Manager while connected via WiFi

Tags: android-studio

I used to connect my physical device with Android Studio via wireless mode (Wi-Fi). On the first time, when I connect my physical device using Device Manager, it connects easily. But after 1-2 hour or when system goes in sleep mode, Eventually physical device discoonects automatically from the Device Manager even when connected via WiFi.

I have a MacBook Air with the macOS Monterey operating system, and I'm using the latest version of Android Studio.

[image: DEVICE MANAGER]

**Issue I'm actually facing:**

My device disconnects automatically after sometime when I already connected via WiFi. I've tried both methods - "**Pair using QR code**" and "**Pair using pairing code**" to connect the device and my Machine (MacBook). The device shows that it's connected, but the machine just says "connecting" and never fully connects. After a few minutes, it shows an error message.
However, sometimes it reconnects automatically without me doing anything.

> After disconnecting from the Device Manager, I used to connect using the cable connectivity because Device Manager just shows **connecting** for a few minutes and then shows an error.

**I figured out why it sometimes disconnects on its own:**

- Wi-Fi is not connecting or disconnects from the network
- Device either switch Wi-Fi networks or disconnects from the network
- Machine and device are not connected to the same wireless network
- Machine or Device goes idle for sometime
- Sometimes disconnected automatically without any reason (**That's the actual issue which I facing**)

**Ways I tried but didn't get the expected results:**

- Re-connected Machine and Device on the same wireless network
- Invalidating caches and restarting Android Studio
- Restarting Android Studio
- Revoking/reaccepting USB debugging authorization
- Try connecting in a different way by using either "Pair using QR code" or "Pair using pairing code"
- I also looked at the official documentation but not fount a suitable solution: [Troubleshoot device connection](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device?utm_source=android-studio-2021-1-1#troubleshoot)

**Reviewed other similar questions:**
I have examined questions already posted on Stack Overflow regarding the same issue, but I have not found a suitable solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While debugging I thought, There is a glitch in the Android Studio but the results are totally different. I debugged the issue & found mobile device is also a cause of auto-disconnecting from the Device Manager while connected via Wi-Fi in Android Studio.

> Just Restart the physical device & try to reconnect with Device Manager in Android Studio using the **Pair device with QR code** or **Pair device with pairing code**. It works 100%.

**Another Way:**

- Go to **Settings**
- Select **Developer options**
- Turn off **Wireless debugging**
- Click on **"Revoke USB debugging authorisations"**
- Again turn on **Wireless debugging** and Allow wireless debugging
- Now pair the device using **Pair device with QR code** or **Pair device with pairing code** with Device Manager in Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Mac user, but on Windows, the wifi connection to Android is also buggy. I have experienced the same error that you experience. There is no solution for that. But, there is a way to make it work 100%.

- The laptop will connect to the WiFi.
- Laptop will open a Mobile hotspot (idk if it is available in Mac)
- Mobile's Wifi will connect to that hotspot.
- for the first time pair with code and then always connect

  ./adb connect 192.168.137.254:37785

==> This will always work. Without a hotspot, you will experience all sorts of problems.

Comment: I resolved this issue for me. Thanks for your contribution